# Adding span to text causes scrolling to cursor position inside EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, html

To be more specific I've done small example of this behaviour.

**Layout:**

```
  <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_for_et"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Long text there" />
    </ScrollView>
```

**Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Adding random span to text
            editText.getEditableText().setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 100, 500, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }, 7000);
}
```

So if I set a cursor in some place, and then scrolling text in other position, after 7 seconds passed it will be scrolled back to coursor position. How to avoid this behaviour?

[BitBucket link](https://bitbucket.org/andrey_kidinov/for-so-question/src) for full code of this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution. Issue was in that EditText recieved a focus after execution of `setSpan` method. So I've added `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` to parent element in my view hierarchy ( in my case it was LinearLayout), and OnTouchListener to ScrollView:

```
mScrollViewAroundEt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mCustomEditText.hasFocus()) {
            mCustomEditText.clearFocus();
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

So now EditText do not recieve focus when user scroll.